# How do I loop this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [Odometer](https://github.hubspot.com/odometer/docs/welcome/) to show an animated counter:

```
  setTimeout(function (){
  $('.odometer').html(8567);
}, 1000);
</script>
<script>
window.odometerOptions = {
  duration: 3000
};
```

I would like the counter to start over at the value I've defined in my html (which is 1000) and then count back up to 8567 and repeat indefinitely. I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function loop(){
    setTimeout(function (){
    $('.odometer').html(8567);},1000,loop);

loop();
});
```

But it breaks the counter. I'm assuming I can't mix the `setTimeout` while defining the loop, but don't know what else to try. The 1000 in the `setTimeout` function is just a coincidence and is the delay to start the function after page load.

Comment: try to provide a working snippet where we can debug and help you. If you want to do something in an interval of time without stoping, use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`;

Comment: You're trying to pass a variable (`8567`) which isn't defined to `html()`. You need to pass a string.

Comment: Your loop does the same thing every tick.

Comment: @CalvinNunes Thanks - the first code snippet I provided is working the way it is supposed to (minus those extra <script>s. I just want to expand upon it and have the counter start over and count back up to my pre-determined value of 8567.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repeatedly call a function over time like this you should use [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) not setTimeout.

You need to keep track of the current value of the loop, yours right now is setting the counter to 8567 every time.

```js
const start = 1000;
const max = 1010;
var c = start;
var el = document.getElementById('counter');

function counter() {
  if (c > max) {
    c = start;
  }
  
  el.innerHTML = c + "";
  c++;

}

counter(); // Optional, can exclude if you want to delay starting the timer

setInterval(counter , 1000)
```

```html
<div id="counter"></div>
```

Comment: Actually, I want the counter to always return a pre-determined value, just like the other Odometer examples on this page: https://github.hubspot.com/odometer/docs/welcome/ And I would like it to repeat - which the link also sort of shows, going between two different values on each panel. I just can't figure out how it is being done.